# How to check www.abc.com/?page=xyz is vulnerable to RFI or not?

Tags: known-vulnerabilities, file-inclusion

On my friends website when I typed `www.abc.com/?page=non existing page`, I got page not found error.But when I gave `www.abc.com/?page=www.google.com`  I got blank white page.So is this website vulnerable to RFI? Why did it show blank page instead of error page?

Comment: This cannot be answered unless we know the source code of the application which handles this URL.

Comment: Hey! What do you have against abc.com? I like my news!

Comment: check the error-logs, if you have some.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Generally if you're looking to test for RFI the way to approach it is to place a URL that you have control over as the parameter.  That way then the URL is accessed you can look in the web server logs to see if you had a request from the server your assessing for that page.

As to whether this website is vulnerable, to be honest it's not possible to tell definitively from the information at hand.